# For loop in SwingWorker

Tags: java, swingworker

just want to make clear an understanding on using for loops inside a SwingWorker `doInbackground` method.

For example, I have a list of files stored in `Files` ( `File[] Files = ...` ).

```
scanFiles = new SwingWorker<Object, Object>(){ 
      public Object doInBackground(){
          for( File f : Files ){
             // process file f
          }
      }
}
....
scanFiles.execute();
```

In the above, is it alright to use a for loop inside the `doInBackGround()` method to go through a list of files , or is it better to bring the `for loop` outside the `doInBackground()` method, as in something like this:

```
for ( File f: Files ){
   processFile(f);
}

private void processFile(File f){
    scanFiles = new SwingWorker<Object, Object>(){ 
     public Object doInBackground(){
           // do something with f
     }
    }
}
```

The above are skeleton code and not actual working code. Just for illustration of what I want to do only. That is, I don't want my program to scan files one by one. I want to do something like parallel processing of files...
thanks

Comment: Beware, `SwingWorker` will only (I think) 10 simultaneous threads to run at a time...

Comment: The answer is, it depends.  A single instance`SwingWorker` is, in of it a single `Thread`.  So if you want to process all the files, in the background, but in sequence, then you would use the first method.  If on the other hand you want to process all the files in the background in parallel, then you would use the second one, with the previous warning in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in some of the comments: The appropriate solution heavily depends on how many files you want to process, and what `processFile` actually *does*.

The main difference between your approaches is (as MadProgrammer already said)

- The first one creates *one* background thread that processes *all* the files
- The second one creates *many* background threads, each processing *one* file

The border cases where either of the approaches is not appropriate are analogously:

- The first one may be better when there *many* files, and `processFile` is a *simple* operation
- The second one may be better when there are *few* files and `processFile` is a *complex* operation

But this is only a rough classification, and which one is the "best" approach still depends on other factors.

However, I'd like to propose another solution, that allows you to rather flexibly "shift" between the two extremes: You could create a `List` containing the `File` objects, and split this list into a specified number of "chunks" to let them be processed by the `SwingWorker`.

Sketched here, to show the basic idea: You create a method that processes a list of files with a `SwingWorker`:

```
private void processFiles(final List<File> files) {
    SwingWorker<Object, Object> scanFiles = new SwingWorker<Object, Object>(){ 
        @Override
        public Object doInBackground(){
            // do something with files
        }
    }
}
```

Then, at the call site, you can do the following:

```
// Obtain the list of files to process
File files[] = ...
List<File> fileList = Arrays.asList(files);

// Define the number of workers that should be used
int numWorkers = 10;

// Compute how many files each worker will process
int chunkSize = (int)Math.ceil((double)fileList.size() / numWorkers);

for (int i=0; i<numWorkers; i++) {

    // Compute the part of the "fileList" that the worker will process
    int minIndex = i * chunkSize;
    int maxIndex = i * chunkSize + chunkSize;
    maxIndex = Math.min(maxIndex, fileList.size());
    List<File> chunk = fileList.sublist(minIndex, maxIndex);

    // Start the worker
    processFiles(chunk);
}
```

(This is only a sketch. There may be some index-hassle involved. If desired, I can post a more elaborate version of this. Until now, it only shows the basic idea)

Then, you can define how many worker threads you would like to use (maybe even depending on the number of `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()`).

Comment: Using Executors is a simpler and more elegant way to do this job. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html

Comment: @Ezequiel It depends. One has to assume that the asker has a *reason* to use a `SwingWorker`. Particularly, that he wants to use some of the `publish/process/done` infrastructure that is offered by it. If there is *no* interaction with the EDT at all, then one would certainly do this with an `Executor`. But the general strategy of keeping the number of workers flexible by defining chunks of a list that each task is responsible for is applicable there as well. (And of course, one could  also interact with the EDT from an `Executor` task using `SwingUtilites.invokeLater`, but less convenient)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to process files parallely you must spawn some thread workers so the second sample should be your choice. You can inform the UI, or other components of your program, about the progress of processing files using following methods : `protected void process(List<V> chunks)`, `protected final void publish(V... chunks)`

```
private void processFile(File f){
    scanFiles = new SwingWorker<Object, Object>(){ 
     public Object doInBackground(){
           publish(V... chunks)
     }
    }
}

protected void process(List<V> chunks) {
  //do something with intermediate data, for example show progress in the ui
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether one should generally recommend the second example. Imagine there are 100000 files, and `processFile` only prints the file name to the console: Then creating 100000 instances of `SwingWorker` would be an overkill. It certainly depends on *what* the workers are actually doing. There even are many cases where *parallel* file operations are *slower* than single-threaded ones, because the hard disk head has to do more jumps in order to serve the thread that currently wants to be served...

Comment: @Marco13 SwingWorker will be executed in a ExecutorService (A Thread pool). So probably you will not overkill anything.

Comment: @Ezequiel The "overkill" referred to the fact that creating 100000 instances of a `SwingWorker` where each of them only does a "trivial" task is certainly not appropriate: There is quite some overhead involved when creating and executing a `SwingWorker` instance (at least compared to a simple `Runnable` that is passed to an `ExecutorService`), so one should probably go for a solution where each `SwingWorker` does an amount of work that is worth this overhead. I tried to elaborate that a little in my answer.